# libusbdotnet can not find RFIDeas USB HID device

Tags: usb, rfid, libusbdotnet

I am running windows 7x64 connecting to a RFIDeas USB reader (Part# RDR-80582AKU). Using device manager, I found its vendor & product ID as HID\VID_0C27&PID_3BFA&REV_1623. 
My .NEt app referenced Libusdotnet,LibUsb.Common, also installed libusb-win32-driver. When running , it show "Device Not Found", I searched and did not find anything related my problem, below is my code. TIA.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Info;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace RFIDeas_cs
{
class Program
{
    public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;

    #region SET YOUR USB Vendor and Product ID!

    public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x0c27, 0x3bfa);

    #endregion

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

        try
        {
            // Find and open the usb device.
            MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

            // If the device is open and ready
            if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

            // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
            // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the 
            // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is 
            // an interface of a device; it does not require or support 
            // configuration and interface selection.
            IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
            if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
            {
                // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used, 
                // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

                // Select config #1
                wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

                // Claim interface #0.
                wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
            }

            // open read endpoint 1.
            UsbEndpointReader reader = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);


            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
            {
                int bytesRead;

                // If the device hasn't sent data in the last 5 seconds,
                // a timeout error (ec = IoTimedOut) will occur. 
                ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 5000, out bytesRead);

                if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}:No more bytes!", ec));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes read", bytesRead);

                // Write that output to the console.
                Console.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone!\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine((ec != ErrorCode.None ? ec + ":" : String.Empty) + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (MyUsbDevice != null)
            {
                if (MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
                {
                    // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
                    // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the 
                    // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is 
                    // an interface of a device; it does not require or support 
                    // configuration and interface selection.
                    IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                    {
                        // Release interface #0.
                        wholeUsbDevice.ReleaseInterface(0);
                    }

                    MyUsbDevice.Close();
                }
                MyUsbDevice = null;

                // Free usb resources
                UsbDevice.Exit();

            }

            // Wait for user input..
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried similar code from here with same result: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714930/libusbdotnet-no-devices-found-when-calling-usbdevice-alldevices)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with Filter Enabled. 
Download & run setup LibUsbDotNet_Setup.2.2.8.exe
select appropriate filter for your input device, in my case vendor ID 0c27